# How to highlight variable name dynamically using the VS Code Extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want my VS Code extension to be able to highlight a variable name when it is initialized. For example, when `x = 4`, I want `x` to be highlighted in red. This is the code I have written so far:

`extension.ts`

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((event) => {
        const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if(activeEditor){
            const currentLineIndex = activeEditor.selection.active.line;
            const lineContent = activeEditor.document.lineAt(currentLineIndex);
            const variableRegularExpression = new RegExp("^\\s{0,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{0,}\\s{0,}=\\s{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\\s{0,}(//[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,}$");
            if(variableRegularExpression.test(lineContent.text)){
                const variableName = lineContent.text.split('=')[0].trim();
                const startIndex = lineContent.text.indexOf(variableName);
                const endIndex = startIndex + variableName.length;
                const variableRange = new vscode.Range(currentLineIndex, startIndex, currentLineIndex, endIndex);
            }
        }
    })
);
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the extension to understand dynamically when a variable is initialized. I compare the line currently being edited to a regular expression, and if there is a match, the range of the variable is extracted.

Is there a way to highlight this range with a color dynamically? Is this a good way of implementing dynamic highlighting for variable initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Semantic Token Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide).

You can implement a Semantic Token Highlighter which reads from an array of objects with the position of the text you wish to highlight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Charles. I tried implementing Semantic Token Highlighting, but I could not succeed. Could you please take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744702/semantic-highlighting-not-working-in-my-vs-code-extension