# Semantic highlighting not working in my VS Code extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide) to implement semantic highlighting on my VS Code extension. This is the code I wrote:

`MySemanticTokenProvider.ts`

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

const tokenTypes = ['variable'];
const tokenModifiers = ['declaration'];
export const legend = new vscode.SemanticTokensLegend(tokenTypes, tokenModifiers);

export const provider: vscode.DocumentSemanticTokensProvider = {
    provideDocumentSemanticTokens(document: vscode.TextDocument): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.SemanticTokens> {
      // analyze the document and return semantic tokens 
      const tokensBuilder = new vscode.SemanticTokensBuilder(legend);
      // highlight the characters from position 1, 1 to position 1, 5
      tokensBuilder.push(
        new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(1, 1), new vscode.Position(1, 5)),
        'variable',
        ['declaration']
      );
      return tokensBuilder.build();
    }
};

export const documentSelector = { language: 'mylanguage', scheme: 'file' };
```

`settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": "configuredByTheme"
}
```

`mylanguagetheme.json`

```
{
    "name": "mylanguage",
    "type": "light",
    ...
    "semanticHighlighting": true,
    "semanticTokenColors": {
        "variable.declaration:mylanguage": {
            "foreground": "#0f8f90"
    }
}
```

`extension.ts`

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import {legend, provider, documentSelector} from './MySemanticTokenProvider';
...
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.languages.registerDocumentSemanticTokensProvider(documentSelector, provider, legend)
);
```

Based on my code, I would expect that the characters from position (1, 1) to position (1, 5) in the editor are highlighted; however, semantic highlighting is not working. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does the provider run at all? What happens if you add a breakpoint inside `provideDocumentSemanticTokens` ?

Comment: I don't think the provider is running. Nothing happens if I add a breakpoint inside `provideDocumentSemanticTokens`. I also wrote a `console.log()` statement inside  `provideDocumentSemanticTokens`, and nothing was printed to the debug console.

Comment: Looks like your provider is not being registered properly. Try to add a breakpoint after the `context.subscriptions.push` to see if it works properly.

Comment: I am not sure how it is supposed to work exactly, but by using breakpoints, I can tell the program does not run the `provideDocumentSemanticTokens` method. I can't find any difference between my implementation and that of the documentation, however

Comment: It could be that your extension is not activated for that specific file. Try to type a few words in your file to see if it triggers the provider. Also, make sure that your file is recognised as a `mylanguage`.

Comment: My extension is actually activated, and works pretty well, except for semantic highlighting. Have you ever implemented semantic highlighting? If so, did you implement it exactly as shown in the documentation?

Comment: I have, [here](https://github.com/Sarrus1/sourcepawn-vscode/blob/6ce34a79bed406f9c8ff76f2f3b5d3303ea41c80/client/src/Providers/spProviders.ts#L378-L398) is my implementation. The only difference I could see is that I'm using a class instead of an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238673/discussion-between-6cloud9-and-charles).